# Why is mem_fn failing to compile when used with smatch::str?

Tags: c++

This looks straightforward and innocent enough, yet fails with pages of "failed substitutions" at the call to `f(m)`. Why is that?

```
string const input = "The quick brown fox.";
std::regex const words("[^\\s]+");

auto f = std::mem_fn(&std::smatch::str);
std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(input.begin(), input.end(), words);
std::smatch m = *i;

string first_word = f(m);
```

http://ideone.com/nsN8A1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [`str` takes an argument](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/match_results/str/). Normally it defaults to `0`, but a `mem_fn` doesn't bring along default argument values and thus it must be explicitly supplied.

```
string first_word = f(m, 0);
```

http://ideone.com/nfuTFX